# Is it a good practice if we always locally precede \href with \sloppy?

Tags: line-breaking, best-practices, links

Is it a good practice if we always locally precede `\href` with `\sloppy` as follows?

```
if you are interested to know the details, 
please contact me at {\sloppy
\href{mailto:asdfkoafdkfaldfkafsdfkdf@kdsoffkdlfasdfjaldf.xxx}
{asdfkoafdkfaldfkafsdfkdf@kdsoffkdlfasdfjaldf.xxx}}.
```

Comment: Best email address ever...

Comment: How did you get the idea to do that?

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Because I previously assumed that `\sloppy` can work in a word scope. I did not know it must be in a paragraph scope.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No.  Placed there the command `\sloppy` has no effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[width=7cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

If you are interested to know the details, 
please contact me at {\sloppy
\href{mailto:asdfkoafdkfaldfkafsdfkdf@kdsoffkdlfasdfjaldf.xxx}
{asdfkoafdkfaldfkafsdfkdf@kdsoffkdlfasdfjaldf.xxx}}.

If you are interested to know the details, 
please contact me at
\href{mailto:asdfkoafdkfaldfkafsdfkdf@kdsoffkdlfasdfjaldf.xxx}
{asdfkoafdkfaldfkafsdfkdf@kdsoffkdlfasdfjaldf.xxx}.

\end{document}
```

[image: No sloppy effect]

The command `\sloppy` only works with complete paragraphs, so one would need to write

```
{\sloppy
If you are interested to know the details, 
please contact me at {
\href{mailto:asdfkoafdkfaldfkafsdfkdf@kdsoffkdlfasdfjaldf.xxx}
{asdfkoafdkfaldfkafsdfkdf@kdsoffkdlfasdfjaldf.xxx}}.
\par
}
```

or use `sloppypar`.  However, this is often not satisfactory.  Some discussion may be found in [l2tabu](ftp://cam.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf).  In your case, I suggest you use

```
\url{asdfkoafdkfaldfkafsdfkdf@kdsoffkdlfasdfjaldf.xxx}
```

[image: url example]

Hyperref should be able to deduce the link type and it provides more break points LaTeX can use.  For a more realistic example, where there are more `.`'s in the email address, this gives rather good results:

```
If you are interested to know the details, 
please contact me at 
\url{asdf.koafdkfa.ldfkaf.sdfkdf@kdso.ffkdlfas.dfjaldf.xxx}.
```

[image: Better url example]